# My dependent variable is first difference stationary. Can I use the original variable?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, dependent-variable

I found my dependent variable is first difference stationary, but does this mean I have to use the first difference as my dependent variable? Or can I use my original variable as my dependent?

My dependent variable is $\log(Y_t)$.  I found that $\log(Y_t)-\log(Y_{t-1})$ is stationary. Can I then use my original $\log(Y_t)$ in my model, or do I have to use the above?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the regressors. If some of them are also I(1) and there is no [cointegration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration) between these and the dependent variable, you cannot use the levels of the latter. You must use first difference. Otherwise you are risking a [spurious result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship). If they are cointegrated, then you can. In this case you are estimating the long-run relationship between variables. It might be more convenient/informative in the latter case however to estimate the [error-correction model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_model), where the dependent variable is in first differences.

Any decent econometric textbook of time-series will have a treatment of these topics. I suggest you have a look at one.